# How do I find the line of my code causing an error when the stacktrace only shows native methods in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, stack-trace

The short question is when using eclipse, how can I find out what line of my code triggered the error in cases where the stacktrace and debugger call stack don't reveal anything other than Android native methods.

I have been trying for a while to debug a program and have hit a bit of a wall. To give some background on the problem , my Android App crashes when I rotate my screen and I get the following stack trace:
[image: Stack trace]

From this stack trace, I can see that there is a Class Cast exception where a LinearLayout is trying to be cast as a Textview. What I don't know is where in the code this exception took place. Towards the bottom of the stack trace, the cause is just being explained when it cuts off with a "...55 more". So I started looking around for ways of extending the log cat and the only way I found only worked with extending the printStackTrace method on a caught exception. 
My next attempt was to run this on the debugger and examine the call stack when the exception was thrown. What I found looked like this:

[image: Call Stack]

both the call stack and the stack trace show the calls of several Android native methods but neither show what line in my code invoked the method. What I think is happening is that this code is being run from a handle or event queue. My question is in cases like this, is there a clever way to be able to tell what line of my code triggered this exception? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Try/Catch the entire code and log the exception + stacktrace explicitly?

Comment: I'll put a try catch around the OnCreate() and OnResume() methods for the Activity in which the error is taking place. That's as close as I can get to putting a try-catch around the entire code.

Comment: I put a try catch in the Activity's onCreate() and on Resume() methods. I chose those methods because I know that a screen rotation will cause those methods to be triggered. I also put a try catch in the OnCreateView() method of a fragment I am using. None of them are catching the exception. Are there any other methods called by a screen location that it might be?

Comment: You should take a look at the answer below to see where the screen rotation is called.

Comment: I added the code from the below into my activity, put a breakpoint on it and ran the app in debug. The app crashed before it hit the breakpoint. What other methods are involved in a screen rotation that might trigger the crash?

Comment: How can you be sure that you've put the try/catches in the right class? All I can say is... put more of them in.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. Let me know if you think of anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen rotation fires the following activity delegate

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

You can start by debugging your activity state from this place.
Just validate that all activity/fragment members are still available and nothing was released.

Comment: I put a breakpoint on super.onConfigurationChanged(). The app crashed before it hit that point.

Comment: Since I don't see your full code just general advice, I suggest you to remove iteratively your activity stuff so you can figure out what causes such  anomaly.